# JQuery $.ajax "async: false" bug?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I would appreciate your opinion/advice on the following

**Scenario**

HTML has PDF file nick name, back end has URL for each nick.

The link URL is always `download.php?what=%PDF_Nick%` to ensure download for JS disabled clients.

For JS enabled clients I do JQuery AJAX call and rewrite link URL from `download.php?what=%PDF_Nick%` to http://examplesite.com/requestedPFF.pdf to activate download from the client. I set `"async: false"` to allow AJAX get new url.

**Problem**

AJAX returns valid script rewriting JS url variable, but `location.href` runs again to the initial url, creating extra back end call

Do you think it's related to the bug ignoring `"async: false,"` definition or it's mistake I've made and missed to catch?

Thank you in advance

## HTML code

```
    <a href="/download.php?what=PDF_A" onclick="javascript:download
    ('PDF_A')">Download</a>
```

## JS code

```
function download ( what )  {

   var url = "download.php?what="+what;

   $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "download.php?ajax=true",
      data: "what=" + what
      async: false,
      dataType: "script"
  });

  // if AJAX got the download URL I expect actual download to start:
  location.href = url;
}
```

## Back end (download.php) code

```
$myPDF = array();
$myPDF["PDF_A"] = "PDF_A.pdf";
....
$url = "http://examplesite.com/" . $myPDF["PDF_A"];
...
if ( $_GET["ajax"] === "true" ) {
    // overwrite JS url variable
    print('url = "'.$url.'";');
} else {
    header("Location: ". $url );
    header("Connection: close");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You're encountering a scoping problem here. The URL variable in your JS code is declared via the var keyword inside the scope of the download function. This means that only code inside the download function can modify that particular url value.

The script returned from the download.php is modifying the URL value in the global scope (on the browser, this is the "window" object), which is *not* the same value as the url inside the scope of the download function.

If you don't use the 'var' keyword on the declaration of the url variable, it will be created automatically in the global scope and your code will function as you expect.

I agree with the others, that your design is inherently flawed and should be revisited, however.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a reason you disable the asynchronous nature of the AJAX request? it will lock the browser until the request is completed.
You are better off using a callback instead:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "download.php?ajax=true",
  data: "what=" + what,
  dataType: "script",
  success: function(msg) {
      location.href = url;
  }
});
```

Comment: Modern browsers still _actually_ lock up? I struggle to believe this. Async requests are completely overrated.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use a synchron ajax call with **.responseText** like in this example:

```
var html = $.ajax({
  url: "some.php",
  async: false
}).responseText;
```

For your code this means:

```
function download ( what )  {
  var url = "download.php?what="+what;

  location.href = $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "download.php?ajax=true",
       data: "what=" + what
       async: false,
       dataType: "script"
  }).responseText;
}
```

Comment: I was using success to pass back my variable using a synchronous call that wasn't working. This helped massively, thanks. That being said I'll be looking to correct my code to make it asynchronous however there are mitigating factors.